# Setup Windows 8.1 and Install Driver without User Interaction

Tags: windows, drivers, installation

I have an ASUS Windows 8 Tablet that has been acting up recently, so I re-installed Windows 8.1 on it. The problem is, the touch screen driver didn't install with Windows, so I have no way to set up the OS or install said driver (which is the SOC Driver Package on the ASUS site). Is there any way I could do this remotely somehow?

Comment: Can you attach USB input devices?

Comment: No, all there is is a Micro-USB port.

Comment: There are micro USB keyboards, as well as adaptors. Short of that, did you contact ASUS for support? 8.1 should have at least a generic driver to allow you to complete installation. Not to mention that the OEM should have included it. Since this is a tablet I am assuming you used the "refresh my PC" feature, not a clean 8.1 disk?

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need us unattended installation, since remote options won't be available during installation. This is possible, but is designed for IT departments deploying Windows to multiple systems. Without using a custom Windows image this will require a removable storage device. The documentation I found mentions a USB drive (they make micro USB flash drives), though it might work with an SD card too, if you have that option.

This is my source: [Automate Windows Setup (Microsoft Technet)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825162.aspx)

You can create an "answer file" that stores the configuration settings that Windows normally asks the user for. This is a complicated XML file, you can find a sample [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn621892.aspx). This file is placed on the root of your USB drive, and named `Autounattend.xml`. I have not been able to determine if this will actually work when using the 8.1 reset feature, though I don't see why not unless it's already using its own answer file.

Creating the file can be done with the System Image Manager from the [Windows ADK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982). I also found an online tool, though I can't confirm it's veracity: [Windows 8.1 Answer File Generator](http://windowsafg.no-ip.org/win8.1x86_x64.html). It certainly looks like it should work.

Aside from this, there are micro USB keyboards (as well as adaptors) that you could use to complete the installation process.

However, there is a chance you have a much worse problem than you expect. This is Windows 8.1, an OS designed for touch. It seems insane that any device designed for it would suffer this kind of problem. Windows should have the drivers it needs, especially if it's the OEMs version. This leads me to believe that you may have a significant hardware problem, and you may need to contact ASUS for support/RMA if your device is under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling remote desktop remotely from a PC on your home network using the advice here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/remotely-enable-or-disable-remote-desktop-on-a-windows-server/

Then perhaps use remote desktop connection, or the windows app here:

http://www.7tutorials.com/how-use-remote-desktop-app-windows-81

I've not tried this myself, but I hope it gets you further on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no network access, as I cannot connect to WiFi in the tablet, and there is no Ethernet port, so that will not work.

Comment: Not sure then, sorry. Shame there doesn't seem to be something like the Android development shell for Windows 8 tablets. Perhaps you could look at Windows App development forums and ask if there is any way of remote shell over USB... those guys are more likely to have come into situations such as these. Sorry I couldn't be more help!